# Deno の http/file_server.ts でカスタムの 404 ページを追加したい

Tags: javascript, deno

Denoでファイルサーバーを書いているのですが、カスタムの404ページを追加するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

これが最適解ではない気もしますが、単純に`serveDir`を使用している場合404のときはresponse#statusが404を持っているので、任意のカスタムレスポンスを代わりにreturnすることでカスタム404が使用可能です。

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.151.0/http/server.ts";
import { serveDir } from "https://deno.land/std@0.151.0/http/file_server.ts";
import {
  Status,
  STATUS_TEXT,
} from "https://deno.land/std@0.151.0/http/http_status.ts";

serve(async (req) => {
  const res = await serveDir(req, {
    fsRoot: "./static/",
    showDirListing: true,
  });
  if (res.status === Status.NotFound) {
    return new Response("404 not found", {
      status: Status.NotFound,
      statusText: STATUS_TEXT[Status.NotFound],
      headers: {
        "content-type": "text/html",
      },
    });
  }
  return res;
});
```